# Existence-Uniqueness theorem,Lipschitz condition and limits

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, limits

While doing existence-uniqueness theorem , I came across the following problem :
$$
f(x,y) = 4x^3y/x^4+y^2 , x\neq0,y\neq0 $$

$$ f(x,y) = 0  , when x=y=0 $$      with initial condition y(0)=0

I was able to understand the existence portion, but somewhat proving uniqueness of solutions I came across the following problem:

Using Lipschitz condition,
$$
|f(x,y)-f(x ,z)|/|y-z| $$  where (x,y) (x,z) are assumed to be in R.

substituting the function value, we get
$$
{|[4(x^3)y/(x^4)+(y^2)] - |[4(x^3)z/(x^4)+(z^2)]|}/|y-z|$$

which after solving , results in

$${4|x^3|.|(x^4)-yz|}/{|(x^4)+(y^2)|.|(x^4)+(z^2)|}  $$ The source I am looking into says that this tends to infinity as x tends to zero. How can we prove that the limiting value of this final result tends to infinity as x tends to zero.

Once , it is proved that limiting value tends to infinity ,lipschitz conditon is violated and we get the desired result that solution do  exist but nothing can be said about the uniqueness.

Also, this method seems little bit complicated , Is there any other way of proving the uniqueness? If,there is one,please support with answers.